# tmpfs /run 99% used, but it is not, so postgresql unable to start

Tags: linux, postgresql, tmpfs

Today I rebooted my home server and got error in postgres log:

> 2022-09-15 10:35:19.926 +07 [5312] FATAL:  could not write lock file
> "postmaster.pid": No free space on device pg_ctl:
> could not start server Examine the log output.

I checked /run and in fact found that disk is full, 99% used:
[image]

Then I checked with **df -h** and found that in fact only 1% used:

[image]

Then i googled more, tried remount /run with more space and mc shows again that /run is full. And of course I tried reboot. What can cause this problem and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, problem was found: I am an idiot.

Free space problem is not about /run free space, it is about new ssd free space. I copied database to this drive under root user and seen that it is abount 100GB free space. But non-root users seen that it is no free space, because space was reserved for root.